# My web server and web browser appear to be using port 80 at the same time

Tags: macos, port, lsof

If I, on OS X,

1. Start Firefox.
2. Start Google Chrome.
3. Start a Ruby on Rails server on port 80 (using RVM)

   ```
   rvmsudo rails -p 80
   ```
4. Use lsof to look at what is running on port 80

   ```
   sudo lsof -i:80
   ```

Then I see "ruby", "firefox", and "Google" in the output.

I hear all the time that only one process can listen on a port. How can all of these use port 80 at the same time? How is the way Firefox and Chrome are using the port different from the way Rails is using the port?

Comment: How did you conclude that the listed porcesses really _listen_ on your _local_ port 80?

Comment: I know Rails is listening (through WEBrick) because, well, it's a web server, and I can make requests from a web browser to the Rails server on port 80, using for example the URL http://localhost/

Comment: However, I think I was wrong that Firefox and Chrome are using the _local_ port 80 at all.

Answer (score 1):

After learning about and trying `sudo lsof -i` and `sudo lsof -iTCP`, and reading ["Do web browsers use different outgoing ports for different tabs?"](https://superuser.com/q/1055281), I think I'm just reading the output from `lsof` incorrectly.

Here's an example:

```
$ sudo lsof -iTCP:80
COMMAND  PID  USER      FD  TYPE     DEVICE  SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
...
firefox xxxx  user  xxxxxx  IPv4  xxxxxxxxx    xxxxxx   TCP 192.168.0.100:12345->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Looking at this example and other output from `sudo lsof -i` I think it's pretty clear that this line from Firefox appears in the output because Firefox is connecting **to** port 80 on a remote server, **from** the local port 12345. Firefox is not connecting to a remote server **from** the local port 80.

I don't know if it is possible for a client like Firefox to connect from port 80 while a local server is listening on port 80, but what is happening here at least doesn't seem to challenge that idea, because that is not what Firefox is doing.

`sudo lsof -i:80 -s TCP:^LISTEN` shows the connections to port 80 on remote computers, unless a local client uses local port 80 to connect to something. It's strange there doesn't seem to be an option to just list which *local* ports are in use.

Comment: Only one socket descriptor can exist for a specific port on one operating system instance. Using the notion of "processes" here is inaccurate, though, because it is possible to share that descriptor with child processes. Obviously, the basic idea is that no further discrimination is needed above transport layer, which makes sense because it's inefficient. The operating system will not associate more than one socket descriptor with a local port (see `man 3posix connect`). Also, client-side port numbers usually start at 1000 already by convention to distinguish them from server-side ports.

Comment: Also, the random port that an application uses (a browser asking the OS for a port) will be from a high range, certainly above 1024.

Answer (score 0):

Generally all browsers ( client side ) connecting to port 80 on web server ( server side ). So at the server side only port 80 is on listening state. Browsers use any TCP connection to port 80 on web server.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: `a port cannot be shared`

As you only have one IP and you may be recieving a lot of data coming to you at the same exact time, ports are being used to send the data to the process meant to recieve it. This lead us to the first line: `ports cannot be shared`.

Server side processes have an specific port and they never change it unless you do so but, in the other hand, the client just opens a random high port and connects to the server. That port may be used again but the same process again or not, but you never know and it doesn't matter.

Comment: That’s not a good way of putting it. Strictly speaking, the tuple (local IP address, local TCP port, remote IP address, remote TCP port) needs to be unique. Of course, some implementations may impose more restrictions to keep it simple.